# how to get the status of NPAPI plugin loaded in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, npapi

I have developed a NPAPI plugin. Google chrome 32 will stopped the support for NPAPI plugin. So now chrome ask permission for plugin support.My problem is If a user close the permission then How do i know the status of the plugin ? loaded or not . I am using object tag for load the plugin

Comment: It's incorrect to say that Chrome stopped supporting NPAPI in version 32. Plugins now require user action to run, but that's not at all the same as not being supported. If 32 didn't support NPAPI then you'd always know the status of the plugin: not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If navigator.plugins shows that the plugin is installed, the object tag is in the DOM, but properties or methods that you have on your NPAPI object aren't there after 0.5 seconds or so, you can pretty much expect that either the plugin crashed or has been blocked.

Comment: if you consider it the correct answer, it would be polite to mark it as the correct answer =] welcome to stackoverflow